# After new SQL Server 2008 installation cannot connect to localhost through windows authentication

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just finished an install of SQL Server 2008 and when it came ot the screen where it asks you if you want to connect through windows authentification or mixed mode I chose mixed mode. I supplied an sa password and then where it asks what accounts are part of the system admins I did not chose to add myself but added the computer's "administrators" account -- which I am a part of. I did not add myself because I am prepping this machine to be used as the base image for a team of developers and thought that if I added myself then I would also be adding myself as the admin for everyone who uses this image. I thought that adding "administrators" would be smart since I know that anyone who uses this image will also be a part of the administrators for that machine. SQL Server is only being added to the machine for local development and for the client tools to access our company's dev/staging/prod SQL Servers.

I just fired up SQL Management Studio and tried connecting to localhost with windows authentification and I am being prompted for a password. Not what I wanted...How do I fix this without a reinstall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect to the server with SQL Management Studio with `sa` login, add your windows user in Security->Logins and give this new login `sysadmin` role.

About server-level roles you can read here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188659.aspx.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! Is this the same thing that everyone who uses this image should do, or is there a better way?

Comment: @VanceSmith Sorry, I don't understand what do you mean by "image".

Comment: No worries. What I mean is that I am setting up a machine to be used by everyone in a development team. We will create an "image" of this machine and install it on each developer's computer. Now knowing this, if you reread my original post it may make even more sense. :-)

Comment: @VanceSmith If you ask if it is good practice to use Windows user as SQL Server administrator than, I think, yes it is because you don't need to remember many logins and passwords for different applications and services.

Comment: @VanceSmith Having read your last comment, I think it is a good approach. But I wouldn't say "everyone who uses this image should do" for there can be other ways of doing this. But any way, keep `sa` password in secret.

Comment: So what would be the best way to insure that anyone who gets a pc created from this image is automatically a sql server administrator for the local installation of SQL Server?

Comment: @VanceSmith If anyone will have the same Windows login than this will be the best way if not you'd better ask for help on http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server. Hope I helped you.